# Python socket getting the error “connection refused error 111”

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have a problem connecting with the socket.
I wrote a code whose purpose is to get the serial number of the hard disk from a client and send it to the server.
If I run the server and the client code on my local machine, it works fine.
When I try to run the server on the real server and the client on the real client (2 different machines) I’m getting the error:
“Connection refused error 111”

This is my client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os, socket
from time import sleep


def serialNumber():
    """Find the product serial number"""
    serialtest = "smartctl -a -i /dev/sda2 > /root/Desktop/serialTest.txt"
    grepp = "grep 'Serial Number:' /root/Desktop/serialTest.txt > /root/Desktop/NewserialTest.txt"
    sedd = "sed -i 's/Serial Number:    //g' /root/Desktop/NewserialTest.txt"
    os.system(serialtest)
    os.system(grepp)
    os.system(sedd)
    try:
        with open (r"/root/Desktop/NewserialTest.txt","r") as data:
            global newserial
            newserial = data.readline().strip()
    except:
        return "File not found!"
    try:
        os.rename(r'/root/Desktop/NewserialTest.txt',rf'/root/Desktop/{newserial}.txt')
        os.remove(r"/root/Desktop/serialTest.txt")
    except:
        return "File not found!"
    return ""


print(serialNumber())

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ip = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5555
    s.connect((ip,port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(f"UNABLE to connect! you got error:\n{e}.")
    exit(-1)
try:
    with open(rf'/root/Desktop/{newserial}.txt', "rb") as fd:
            toSend = fd.read()
            s.send(toSend)
except socket.error as e:
    print(f"you got error:\n{e}.")
```

This is my Server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os, socket
from _thread import *


server_socket = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 5555


try:
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(f"You have a error:\n{str(e)}")

print("\nWaiting for connection....\n")
server_socket.listen(100)


while True:
    # Recive the serial number from the client
    sc, address = server_socket.accept()
    print(address)
    f = open(r'/root/Desktop/LAB_Test/NewserialTest.txt' ,'wb') #open in binary
    while (True):
        l = sc.recv(1024)
        f.write(l)
        if not l:
            break
    f.close()
    sc.close()

    try:
        with open (r'/root/Desktop/LAB_Test/NewserialTest.txt',"r") as data:
            global newserial
            newserial = data.readline().strip()
    except:
        print("File not found!")
    os.rename(r'/root/Desktop/LAB_Test/NewserialTest.txt',rf'/root/Desktop/LAB_Test/{newserial}.txt')
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Firewalls could be the problem. Network connectivity could be the problem. Not binding to the correct IP could be the problem (use 0.0.0.0). Or any combination of these..

Comment: @barny - Thanks for your help, I changed the bind to 0.0.0.0, now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the bind to 0.0.0.0, and now it works.